# String epoch time to date format

Tags: hive

Hi I have a question on how to get the date time out from the epoch time.In this case the epoch time is stored as a string.

SELECT from_unixtime(ts)  FROM table A it shows error.

Wrong arguments 'ts': No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (string). Possible choices: *FUNC*(int) *FUNC*(bigint, string) *FUNC*(bigint) *FUNC*(int, string).

Can some one please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question if you have seconds-since-epoch stored as strings or if you have a formatted string for the date.

If your ts column has stuff like 123456789, try

```
SELECT from_unixtime(cast(ts as bigint)) FROM table A...
```

If it's some other format, take a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF and choose among the date functions that accept strings.